# Spring Boot using JDBCTemplate , Hikari and Teradata

Tags: spring, spring-boot, teradata, hikaricp

The application i'm working on is in Spring Boot using Spring JDBCTemplate to connect to Teradata.
We face issues with Idle connections. we have about 6 different environments that create at some point 1672 sessions. 
In order to limit the total pool size and the minimum idle connections i set it to:
    `hikari:
      maximum-pool-size: 3
      minimum-idle: 2`

is there anything else recommend in otder to prevent the number of idle connections?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using Hikari for connection pool, you may use **idleTimeout**. Please refer Hikari [configuration](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#configuration-knobs-baby) for all available properties.